# How to identify which IIS server reponding my http page request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, load-balancing

My website is placed in 8 different IIS servers and controlled using load balancer.
When i request any page, I would like to identify which IIS server (IP or domain name)responds the request? 
How to do this in ASP.Net MVC web application?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the machine you are currently running code on from the current `HttpContext`.

```
  HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName
```

Comment: Should `HttpContext` be used explicitly in `MVC` ?